# Running totals in a SQL view

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, aggregate-functions

I am trying to get running totals in my View in SQL Server 2008

Here is my tables

```
BankAccounts
------------
AccountID (KEY)
Name
Created

Transactions
------------
TransactionID (KEY)
Description
Credit
Debit
TransDate
Created
AccountID
```

Here is my query so far..

```
SELECT t.Created, t.Description, t.Credit, t.Debit, t.TransDate, t.TransactionID, ba.AccountID,
        (isnull(t.Credit,0)-isnull(t.Debit,0))+COALESCE((SELECT SUM(isnull(Credit,0)) - SUM(isnull(Debit,0))
                              FROM Transactions b 
                              WHERE b.TransDate < t.TransDate
                               and b.AccountID = t.AccountID),0)
                                 AS RunningTotal
FROM  Transactions t 
INNER JOIN dbo.BankAccounts ba ON t.AccountID = ba.AccountID
```

What I'm getting is..

```
TransDate               Credit                 Debit                  RunningTotal
----------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------
2011-10-08 20:14:00     NULL                   12                     49.25
2011-10-08 20:14:00     2.11                   NULL                   63.36
2011-10-07 20:14:00     42.25                  NULL                   61.25
2011-10-06 20:14:00     NULL                   12.25                  19
2011-10-05 20:14:00     31.25                  NULL                   31.25
```

What it should look like...

```
TransDate               Credit                 Debit                  Running Total
----------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------- ---------------------
2011-10-08 00:31:32.957 NULL                   12                     51.36
2011-10-08 00:31:32.957 2.11                   NULL                   63.36
2011-10-07 00:31:32.957 42.25                  NULL                   61.25
2011-10-06 00:31:32.957 NULL                   12.25                  19
2011-10-05 00:31:32.960 31.25                  NULL                   31.25
```

I'm really close.. just seems when there are 2 transactions for same day, it doesn't calculate it correctly.. any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used `ROW_NUMBER` AND a `CTE` since you're in 2008

```
WITH transactionTotal AS
(
   SELECT t.Created, t.Description, t.Credit, t.Debit, t.TransDate, t.TransactionID, a.AccountID
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TransDate ASC) AS RowNumber
      , ( ISNULL(t.Credit, 0) - ISNULL(t.Debit, 0) ) AS TransactionTotal
   FROM dbo.Transactions AS t 
   INNER JOIN dbo.BankAccounts AS a ON t.AccountID = a.AccountID
)
SELECT t.Created, t.Description, t.Credit, t.Debit, t.TransDate, t.TransactionID, t.AccountID
   , ( SELECT SUM(tt.TransactionTotal)
       FROM transactionTotal AS tt
       WHERE tt.RowNumber <= t.RowNumber) AS RunningTotal
FROM transactionTotal AS t
LEFT JOIN transactionTotal AS tt ON t.RowNumber = tt.RowNumber + 1
ORDER BY t.TransDate DESC
```

Comment: VERY nice!! Been trying to get this for days, just had to deal with the totals wrong, until now... put this into a view and it works GREAT

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t.Created, t.Description, t.Credit, t.Debit, t.TransDate, t.TransactionID, ba.AccountID,
       coalesce((select sum(ISNULL(Credit,0) - ISNULL(Debit, 0)) 
                 from Transactions
                 where TransactionID <= t.TransactionID and 
                       AccountID = ba.AccountID and
                      convert(date, TransDate) = convert(date, t.TransDate)),0)
        AS [Running Total]

FROM  Transactions t INNER JOIN
         dbo.BankAccounts ba ON t.AccountID = ba.AccountID
```

Comment: doesnt seem to work, and was missing a ( after coalesce... i'll edit the post to show what I'm getting

Comment: I believe the problem might be on the way how you get the smalldate from the date, I'll update my answer

Comment: ok, I updated, see that another change is I replaced 'Running Total' to [Running Total], on my tests 'Running Total' naming it doesn't work

Comment: its close.. its added up now, just not calculating up correctly, if you look at my updated results, you can see how it should look

Comment: I checked, but I can't see how you compute the Running Total in your "good" example: I mean there are the totals for 5, 6, 7 and 8 days so why on 6th are you subtracting the total from the previous day?

Comment: the good example was just using calc.. i'm just starting from oldest, then adding if its a credit, subtracting if debit, will never have both.. in other words, running total of first row will be the sum of all.. last row will be its credit

Comment: I don't think I can help you more, maybe you don't want to include the  current transaction which this leads to TransactionId < t.TransactionId

Answer (score 1):

--I would use the existing identity column to be 100% sure that I am dealing with the correct transaction.

```
SELECT t.Created, t.Description, t.Credit, t.Debit, t.TransDate, t.TransactionID, ba.AccountID,
        (isnull(t.Credit,0)-isnull(t.Debit,0))+COALESCE((SELECT SUM(isnull(Credit,0)) - SUM(isnull(Debit,0))
                              FROM Transactions b 
                              WHERE b.TransactionID < t.TransactionID 
                               and b.AccountID = t.AccountID),0)
                                 AS RunningTotal
FROM  Transactions t 
INNER JOIN dbo.BankAccounts ba ON t.AccountID = ba.AccountID
```

--also if you change the "Less Than" to "Less Than or Equal To", then you don't have to add the current item:

```
SELECT t.Created, t.Description, t.Credit, t.Debit, t.TransDate, t.TransactionID, ba.AccountID,
COALESCE((SELECT SUM(isnull(Credit,0)) - SUM(isnull(Debit,0))
                              FROM Transactions b 
                              WHERE b.TransactionID <= t.TransactionID  
                               and b.AccountID = t.AccountID),0)
                                 AS RunningTotal
FROM  Transactions t 
INNER JOIN dbo.BankAccounts ba ON t.AccountID = ba.AccountID
```

Totals should be :        (Assuming) Starting Balance: 49.25

```
TransDate               Credit            Debit          RunningTotal      
----------------------- ----------------- -------------- ----------------- 
2011-10-08 20:14:00     NULL              12             37.25 
2011-10-08 20:14:00     2.11              NULL           39.36            
2011-10-07 20:14:00     42.25             NULL           81.61
2011-10-06 20:14:00     NULL              12.25          69.36
2011-10-05 20:14:00     31.25             NULL           100.61
```

Answer (score 0):

if this is Oracle, then there are Window functions.  you can use LEAD and/or LAG to perform calculations on the current row with respect to prior or upcoming rows (based on sort order)

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to use this logic with RowNumber and CTE from above. In my scenario, I need the Running Total to be calculated for a combination of two fields: SalesProdLineID and FiscYerPer. Here's what I have coded (in this example, due to the size of the underlying tables I restricted the results to a single Month:

```
 WITH RunningTotal AS
(
   SELECT to2PN.CompanyID, REPLACE(SP.SalesProdLineID, ' Sls PL','') AS SlsPL, vo2PNQtyProd.QtyProdStock,  FP.FiscYearPer, FP.FiscPer, FP.FiscYear
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SP.SalesProdLineID,FP.FiscYearPer  ASC) AS RowNumber
      , ( ISNULL(vo2PNQtyProd.QtyProdStock, 0)  ) AS RunningTotal
   FROM to2PN  (NOLOCK)
 JOIN to2PNProdTempl   (NOLOCK)
     ON to2PN.PNKey = to2PNProdTempl.PNKey
JOIN timItem I  (NOLOCK)
    ON to2PNProdTempl.ItemKey = I.ItemKey
 JOIN timSalesProdLine SP (NOLOCK)
    ON I.SalesProdLineKey = SP.SalesProdLineKey
 JOIN vo2PNQtyProd   (NOLOCK)
     ON to2PNProdTempl.PNProdTemplKey=vo2PNQtyProd.PNProdTemplKey
 JOIN tglFiscalPeriod FP (NOLOCK)
    ON I.CompanyID = FP.CompanyID
        AND to2PN.ComplDateTime BETWEEN FP.StartDate AND Fp.EndDate
WHERE I.ItemID BETWEEN '0000-0' AND '1999-9'
    AND YEAR(to2PN.[ComplDateTime]) = '2018'    --  !! COMMENT OUT for final
    AND MONTH(to2PN.[ComplDateTime]) = 5    --  !! COMMENT OUT for final
)
SELECT t.CompanyID, t.SlsPL, t.QtyProdStock, t.FiscYearPer, t.FiscPer, t.FiscYear
   , ( SELECT SUM(tt.RunningTotal)
       FROM RunningTotal AS tt
       WHERE tt.RowNumber <= t.RowNumber) AS RunningTotal
FROM RunningTotal AS t
LEFT JOIN RunningTotal AS tt ON t.RowNumber = tt.RowNumber + 1
ORDER BY t.FiscYearPer DESC
```

The issue is that once it's got the correct total for the first SalesProdLineID, it simply adds that Running total to the next SalesProdLineID.