# Calculation of balance after each transaction

Tags: sql

I have table like this:

```
cust_id acc_no trans_id  trans_type amount
1111    1001    10   credit     2000.0  
1111    1001    11   credit     1000.0
1111    1001    12   debit      1000.0  
2222    1002    13   credit     2000.0  
2222    1002    14   debit      1000.0
```

I want a Hive query or sql query for every transaction done by a customer the balance should be calculated so.

I want output as follows:

```
cust_id acc_no trans_id  trans_type amount      balance
1111.0  1001.0  10.0     credit    2000.0   2000.0
1111.0  1001.0  11.0     credit    1000.0   3000.0
1111.0  1001.0  12.0     debit     1000.0   2000.0
2222.0  1002.0  13.0     credit    2000.0   2000.0
2222.0  1002.0  14.0     debit     1000.0   1000.0
```

I've tried

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT cust_id, 
               acc_no, 
               trans_id, 
               trans_type, 
               amount, 
               CASE 
                 WHEN Trim(trans_type) = 'credit' THEN ball = 
                 Trim(bal) + Trim(amt) 
                 ELSE ball = Trim(bal) - Trim(amt) 
               end 
        FROM   ban) l;
```

Comment: What platform (PostgreSQL, SQL Server, MySQL)? Why are you converting `int` types to decimal for the first 3 columns?

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO I want sql query to calculate balance. Don't worry about first 3 columns all those are int only.

Comment: @basu Please update your question with the query you have tried.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO i tried with this query select * from ( select cust_id,acc_no,trans_id,trans_type,amount,
case when trim(trans_type)='credit' then ball=trim(bal)+trim(amt) else ball=trim(bal)-trim(amt) end from ban) l;

Comment: But what is your SQL platform ?

Comment: @fabien-thesolution PLSQL

Comment: It sounds like you want a running total for an account, perhaps my answer here will get you in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7732974/210496

Answer (score 4):

This query will do the trick :

```
SELECT t1.cust_id,t1.acc_no,t1.trans_id,t1.trans_type,t1.amount,
       sum(t2.amount*case when t2.trans_type = 'credit' then 1 
                             else -1 end) as balance
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table1 t2 ON t1.cust_id = t2.cust_id AND 
                        t1.acc_no = t2.acc_no AND 
                        t1.trans_id >= t2.trans_id
GROUP BY t1.cust_id,t1.acc_no,t1.trans_id,t1.trans_type,t1.amount
```

See SQLFIDDLE : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b5d8/15/0

EDIT : 
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b5d8/15)

**MySQL 5.5.32 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`cust_id` int, `acc_no` int, `trans_id` int, 
     `trans_type` varchar(6), `amount` int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`cust_id`, `acc_no`, `trans_id`, `trans_type`, `amount`)
VALUES
    (1111, 1001, 10, 'credit', 2000.0),
    (1111, 1001, 11, 'credit', 1000.0),
    (1111, 1001, 12, 'debit', 1000.0),
    (2222, 1002, 13, 'credit', 2000.0),
    (2222, 1002, 14, 'debit', 1000.0)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT t1.cust_id,t1.acc_no,t1.trans_id,t1.trans_type,t1.amount,
       sum(t2.amount*case when t2.trans_type = 'credit' then 1 
                             else -1 end) as balance
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table1 t2 ON t1.cust_id = t2.cust_id AND 
                        t1.acc_no = t2.acc_no AND 
                        t1.trans_id >= t2.trans_id
GROUP BY t1.cust_id,t1.acc_no,t1.trans_id,t1.trans_type,t1.amount
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b5d8/15/0)**:

```
| CUST_ID | ACC_NO | TRANS_ID | TRANS_TYPE | AMOUNT | BALANCE |
|---------|--------|----------|------------|--------|---------|
|    1111 |   1001 |       10 |     credit |   2000 |    2000 |
|    1111 |   1001 |       11 |     credit |   1000 |    3000 |
|    1111 |   1001 |       12 |      debit |   1000 |    2000 |
|    2222 |   1002 |       13 |     credit |   2000 |    2000 |
|    2222 |   1002 |       14 |      debit |   1000 |    1000 |
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but the problem is this query will give us total closing balance but balance should be calculated per every transaction done by customer one account number as I mentioned in table

Comment: No, it gave the balance at every transaction...Have you look at the SQLFIDDLE link

Comment: It is giving answer like this                                         cust_id acc_no trans_id  trans_type amount     balance
1111    1001    10   credit     2000.0          2000 
1111    1001    11   credit     1000.0          2000
1111    1001    12   debit      1000.0          2000
2222    1002    13   credit     2000.0          1000
2222    1002    14   debit      1000.0          1000

Comment: Are you sure ? I see :  cust_id acc_no trans_id trans_type amount balance 1111 1001 10 credit 2000.0 2000 1111 1001 11 credit 1000.0 `3000` 1111 1001 12 debit 1000.0 2000 2222 1002 13 credit 2000.0 `2000` 2222 1002 14 debit 1000.0 1000

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to quantify each transaction (- or +) based on trans_type and then get cumulative sum using window function .

```
SELECT cust_id, 
   acc_no, 
   trans_id, 
   trans_type, 
   amount, 
   Sum (real_amount) 
     OVER (ORDER BY cust_id) AS balance 
FROM   (SELECT cust_id, 
           acc_no, 
           trans_id, 
           trans_type, 
           amount, 
           ( CASE trans_type 
               WHEN 'credit' THEN amount 
               WHEN 'debit' THEN amount *- 1 
             END ) AS real_amount 
    FROM   test) t
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this easily through a `View`, calculating this directly on the table is possible but leads to performance and scalability issues (the database will slow down as the table grows).  By using a `View` the calculation is performed as-needed; if you index the view you can keep the balances up to date without impacting the performance of the transaction table.

If you really insist on it being in the transaction table itself you could possibly use a calculated column which runs a user-defined function to determine the current balance.  However this will depend largey on the specific SQL backend you're using.

---

Here's a basic SELECT Statement which calculates the current balance by Account:

```
select
acc_no, 
sum(case trans_type 
    when 'credit' then amount 
    when 'debit' then amount * -1 
    end) as Amount 
from Transactions
group by acc_no
```

Comment: Note that an indexed view is the next logical step towards a full OLAP cube.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window function:

```
select cust_id, 
acc_no, trans_id, trans_type, amount, 
sum(pre_balance) over (partition by cust_id order by trans_id) as balance
from    
(select cust_id, acc_no, trans_id, trans_type, 
        amount, 
        amount as pre_balance from test 
        where trans_type = 'credit' 
 union
 select cust_id, acc_no, trans_id, trans_type, 
        amount, -amount as pre_balance from 
        test where trans_type = 'debit'
 order by trans_id) as sub;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with current_balances as (
SELECT
       id,
       user_id,
       SUM(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY created ASC) as current_balance
FROM payments_transaction pt
ORDER BY created DESC
)
SELECT
    pt.id,
    amount,
    pt.user_id,
    cb.current_balance as running_balance
FROM
    payments_transaction pt
INNER JOIN
    current_balances cb
ON pt.id = cb.id
ORDER BY created DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

This will work very efficiently for big returns, and won't break on filtering or limiting. Please note that if you select only for one user or a subset of them, provide `user_id` filter in both `current_balances` cte, and the main select to omit whole table scan.

Answer (score 0):

Table (Transaction)
-
"id" "amount" "is_credit"

1     10000     1
2     2000      0
3     5000      1

Query :

SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT id, amount, SUM(CASE When is_credit=1 Then amount Else -amount End) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS balance
FROM `Transaction`
GROUP BY id, amount
)
ORDER BY id ;

Output :

"id" "amount" "is_credit" "balance"

1    10000      1         10000

2    2000       0         8000

3    5000       1         13000