# Calculating quantity of an item in each transaction in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I am working in a company in stock department Consider two table of Export and Stock which Export have following attributes:

```
Export{
ExportDate Date not null,
StockID int not null,
Quantity decimal(10, 2),
};
```

and Stock table has the following attributes:

```
Stock{
ItemID int primary key,
ItemName nvarchar(MAX).
Exist decimal(15, 2)
};
```

So, StockID in Export table is reference with ItemID in Stock table and also when a record is save in Export table it also update the Exist of stock based on stockID in export table which code in VB.Net in Export form on save button like this:

```
Try
        cmd = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Export(ExportDate,StockID,Quantity) VALUES(@ExportDate, @StockID, @Quantity)", con)
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 1000
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StockDate", dateTXT.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StockID", comboStockID.SelectedValue)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", quantityTXT.Text)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MessageBox.show(“Stored”)

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(“Not stored!” ex.Message)

    End Try





    'Updating stock Exist

        Try
        cmd = New SqlCommand("UPDATE Stock SET Exist = Exist - @quantity
         WHERE ItemID = '" & comboStockID.SelectedValue & "'", con)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", qtyTXT.Text)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
 MessageBox.show(“Updated!”)

    Catch ex As Exception

        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

suppose in Stock table values like this:

```
ItemID      ItemName      Quantity
  105      Black color      300
  106      Green color      400
```

But, when I join it shows just 300 in each row, it select like this:

```
 ItemID      ItemName      Quantity
  105      Black color      300
  106      Green color      300
```

I want to join Exist of stock with Export table and in each transaction it must show like this :

```
ExportDate      stockID     Quantity     Exist     
2017/8/24         105          5          295
2017/10/30        105         25          270
```

help me guys how should I do this!!!

Comment: what version of `SQL Server` are you using ?

Comment: Sample data of both tables would be helpful.

Comment: I am using SQL-Server 2014

Answer (score 0):

You can use windows function, this is example code:

```
select exportdate, stockid, quantity, 
sum(pre_balance) over (partition by stockid order by exportdate) as exist  
from 
     (select exportdate, stockid, quantity, -quantity as pre_balance 
      from export 
      union
      select '2017-01-01' as exportdate, itemid as stockid, 
      0 as quantity, exist as pre_balance
      from stock 
      order by exportdate) as sub_query;
```

This is the result:

```
exportdate | stockid | quantity | exist  
------------+---------+----------+--------
 2017-01-01 |     105 |        0 | 300.00
 2017-08-24 |     105 |     5.00 | 295.00
 2017-10-30 |     105 |    25.00 | 270.00
 2017-01-01 |     106 |        0 | 400.00
```

Table source:

```
latihan=> select * from stock ;
 itemid |  itemname   | exist  
--------+-------------+--------
    105 | Black color | 300.00
    106 | Green color | 400.00
(2 rows)

latihan=> select * from export ;
 exportdate | stockid | quantity 
------------+---------+----------
 2017-08-24 |     105 |     5.00
 2017-10-30 |     105 |    25.00
(2 rows)
```

This links is an example about windows function, but in Indonesian and with postgresql:

https://github.com/muntaza/Open_Persediaan/blob/master/perhitungan_saldo.md

And this is links to search on google:

https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+function+ms+sql

This links about stock, in english:

https://callmeranjeet.wordpress.com/2014/09/01/calculating-stock-with-fifo-method-in-sql/

Comment: Thanks dear Muhammad Muntaza for your answer but I do not know Indonesian language:(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18494605/calculation-of-balance-after-each-transaction/48073880#48073880   windows function example